# Why won't my IntelliJ import my local classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I've never had this problem before but check it out:
All of a sudden, IntelliJ tells me it wants to import these classes from org.springframemwork instead of my own.

Problem imports:
ViewNames, Mappings, AttributeNames

Example:
IntelliJ wants to import this
org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeNames;
instead of my AttributeNames!

[image: loca]

Comment: What is above `com` in the tree on the left?

Comment: @Andreas module-src-main-java

Comment: Try to do a clean build.

Comment: Can someone explain the -4 here?

Comment: I am also at a loss for what is going on here, This seems to be on topic, and not a duplicate, so... why did people down-vote this?

Answer (score 3):

My solution:
File | "Invalidate Caches / Restart"

IntelliJ began getting an image of a non-existent directory structure and needs to be refreshed

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes IntelliJ is simply "too quick" and adds an import for some obscure class. Happens to me from time to time, too.

The easiest solution: remove the wrong import, and in "organize imports" gets it wrong again, press option-enter. That suggests "import class", and typically gives you a list of choices to choose from, in case the class name is ambiguous.

Comment: Hey. When I delete imports and get a list of import-ables... I just get the org thymeleaf import. I ended up invalidating the cache and restarting IntelliJ. The cache obviously had some corrupted info! I think